# How to pass unique variables to eventsListiner function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I have a hard time adding events to object and array So:
-i created divs using createElement, added the same class using FOR loop and then appendChild to some other html TAG
-i want to addEvennt to divs and i want to pass unique variables(i from FOR loop)
-it returns i max value; or error or does nothing at all
THX for any kind of answer :D
i know this is simple question but i can't find answer to this anywhere

```js
window.onload = function (){

var sectionHTML = document.getElementById('section');

for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 var div_box = document.createElement('div');
 div_box.className = "box";
 div_box.innerText=i;
 sectionHTML.appendChild(div_box);
}
//adding Events
var getDIV = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
 getDiv[i].addEventListiner("click", function (i) { myFunction(i); })

}

}
myFunction (i) {
 var myString = "PLS HELP THX BRO or SIS " + i;
 alert(myString);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not only pass parameters while adding the handler but also get the index of the child within the parent - I show here how to do both.  Note I added some pre-existing child elements so you could see how that works also.

```js
// immediatly invoked function
(function() {
  var sectionEl = document.getElementById('section-used');
  // add box elements
  let howMany = 5;
  for (let i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
    let childBox = document.createElement('div');
    childBox.className = "box";
    childBox.innerText = i;
    sectionEl.appendChild(childBox);
  }

  // doBBoxClick is called on click of child 
  var doBBoxClick = function(event, additionalParameters) {
    let myString = "Updated I am box " + additionalParameters.index;
    alert(myString); //use value passed (not the child index)
    // do stuff with event and this being the triggering event and caller
    this.classList.add(additionalParameters.newClass);
    console.log("parent:", this.parentNode.classList.value);
    this.parentNode.classList.toggle("togle-color");
    console.log("parent:", this.parentNode.classList.value);

    let index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(this.parentNode.children, this);
    console.log("index:", index); //which one
  }

  // get all boxes and add click event
  var childBoxes = sectionEl.getElementsByClassName('box');
  let howManyBoxes = childBoxes.length;
  console.log("howMany:", howManyBoxes);
  for (let c = 0; c < howManyBoxes; c++) {
    childBoxes[c].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      var additionalParameters = {
        index: c,
        newClass: "other-class"
      };
      doBBoxClick.call(this, event, additionalParameters);
    }, false);

  }

}());
```

```css
  .box {
  border: solid 1px lime;
  margin: 0.5em;
}

#section-used {
  border: solid 2px blue;
}

.other-class {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.thing-added {
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.togle-color {
  color: #44dddd;
  )
```

```html
<div id="section-used" class="outer-thing">
  <div class="box">I am box already here</div>
  <div class="box">I am box already 1</div>
  Me
</div>
```

Comment: This code helped me a lot. Now i don't have to use arrays and FOR loops all the time, like this saves time. Man, for beginner like me this is eye opening :D but it took me some time to proces all that in my mind :D When i level up here, i will be able to give u like.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function (){
  var sectionHTML = document.getElementById('section');
  for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    var div_box = document.createElement('div');
    div_box.className = "box";
    div_box.dataset.box_id = i;
    div_box.innerText=i;
    sectionHTML.appendChild(div_box);
  }
  var getDIV = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
  for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    getDiv[i].addEventListener("click", function () { myFunction(this.dataset.box_id); })
  }    
}
myFunction (i) {
 var myString = "PLS HELP THX BRO or SIS " + i;
 alert(myString);
}
```